# How does foreach package scope R Environments when using as.formula, SE dplyr, and lapply?

Tags: r, dplyr, parallel-foreach, snow, nse

I have a function where I dynamically build multiple formulas as strings and cast them to a formulas with `as.formula`. I then call that function in a parallel process using `doSNOW` and `foreach` and use those formulas through `dplyr::mutate_`.

When I use `lapply(formula_list, as.formula)` I get the error `could not find function *custom_function*` when run in parallel, though it works fine when run locally. However, when I use `lapply(formula_list, function(x) as.formula(x)` it works both in parallel and locally.

**Why?** What's the correct way to understand the environments here and the "right" way to code it?

I do get a warning that says: `In e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) : already exporting variable(s): *custom_func*`

A minimal reproducible example is below.

```
# Packages
library(dplyr)
library(doParallel)
library(doSNOW)
library(foreach)

# A simple custom function
  custom_sum <- function(x){
    sum(x)
  } 

# Functions that call create formulas and use them with nse dplyr:
  dplyr_mut_lapply_reg <- function(df){
    my_dots <- setNames(
      object = lapply(list("~custom_sum(Sepal.Length)"), as.formula),
      nm     = c("Sums")
    )

    return(
      df %>%
      group_by(Species) %>%
      mutate_(.dots = my_dots)
    )
  }

  dplyr_mut_lapply_lambda <- function(df){
    my_dots <- setNames(
      object = lapply(list("~custom_sum(Sepal.Length)"), function(x) as.formula(x)),
      nm     = c("Sums")
   )

    return(
      df %>%
      group_by(Species) %>%
      mutate_(.dots = my_dots)
   )
 }

#1. CALLING BOTH LOCALLY
dplyr_mut_lapply_lambda(iris) #works
dplyr_mut_lapply_reg(iris) #works

#2. CALLING IN PARALLEL
  #Faux Parallel Setup
  cl <- makeCluster(1, outfile="")
  registerDoSNOW(cl)

  # Call Lambda Version WORKS
  foreach(j = 1,
          .packages = c("dplyr", "tidyr"),
          .export   = lsf.str()
          ) %dopar% {
     dplyr_mut_lapply_lambda(iris) 
  }



  # Call Regular Version FAILS
  foreach(j = 1,
          .packages = c("dplyr", "tidyr"),
          .export   = lsf.str()
          ) %dopar% {
     dplyr_mut_lapply_reg(iris) 
  }

  # Close Cluster
  stopCluster(cl)
```

EDIT: In my original post title I wrote that I was using nse, but I really meant using standard evaluation. Whoops. I have changed this accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an exact answer to why here, but the [future](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) package (I'm the author) handles these type of "tricky" globals - they are tricky because they are not part of a package and they are nested, i.e. one global calls another global.  For example, if you use:

```
library("doFuture")
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(1, outfile = "")
plan(cluster, workers = cl)
registerDoFuture()
```

that problematic "Call Regular Version FAILS" case should now work.

Now, the above uses `parallel::makeCluster()` which defaults to `type = "PSOCK"`, whereas if you load doSNOW you get `snow::makeCluster()` which defaults to `type = "MPI"`.  Unfortunately, a full [MPI backend is yet not implemented](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/issues/130) for the future package.  Thus, if you're looking for an MPI solution, this won't help you (yet).

Comment: This looks super helpful! I will certainly investigate this some more, though I will leave the question open so I can hopefully understand the core issue better.